# Target Detection - Algorithm suggestions

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, fft

I am trying to do image detection in C++. I have two images:

Image Scene: 1024x786
  Person: 36x49

And I need to identify this particular person from the scene. I've tried to use Correlation but the image is too noisy and therefore doesn't give correct/accurate results.

I've been thinking/researching methods that would best solve this task and these seem the most logical:

- Gaussian filters
- Convolution
- FFT

Basically, I would like to move the noise around the images, so then I can use Correlation to find the person more effectively.

I understand that an FFT will be hard to implement and/or may be slow especially with the size of the image I'm using.

Could anyone offer any pointers to solving this? What would the best technique/algorithm be?

Comment: Show us the images dude so that we can answer after what we see :0

Comment: Hey - It says I can't upload images?? Basically it's a Grayscale of Wally (scene) and Wally himself.. Any help?

Comment: Resize them, must be the size limit or format. Try Jpeg not greater than 300x300

Answer (score 2):

In Andrew Ng's [Machine Learning class](http://www.ml-class.org/) we did this exact problem using neural networks and a sliding window:

1. train a neural network to recognize the particular feature you're looking for using data with tags for what the images are, using a 36x49 window (or whatever other size you want).
2. for recognizing a new image, take the 36x49 rectangle and slide it across the image, testing at each location. When you move to a new location, move the window right by a certain number of pixels, call it the `jump_size` (say 5 pixels). When you reach the right-hand side of the image, go back to 0 and increment the `y` of your window by `jump_size`.

Neural networks are good for this because the noise isn't a huge issue: you don't need to remove it. It's also good because it can recognize images similar to ones it has seen before, but are slightly different (the face is at a different angle, the lighting is slightly different, etc.).

Of course, the downside is that you need the training data to do it. If you don't have a set of pre-tagged images then you might be out of luck - although if you have a Facebook account you can probably write a script to pull all of yours and your friends' tagged photos and use that.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. It's not really faces (Like, actual faces) It's basically a Where's Wally task. So I could split the images into blocks of the same size and then just move the image along and see which gives the highest correlation, and this is the position. I've tried this and does not give the expected results I want, I've even looked through the blocks AND the Matrix doesn't exist in the scene because of noise issues.

Comment: A correlation isn't really going to work - if the image is shifted over by even a few pixels then the correlation may not be very strong, even if it is the exact same image.

Comment: What would you suggest, other than Correlation? http://codepad.org/Bvxwkqwm is my algorithm at the minute. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: As I put in my original post, I recommend the NN classifier. It's a bit of a generalization of what you're trying to do so you'll have to just have a bunch of pictures of Wally to train the classifier, but that shouldn't be too hard. It will be much better than a correlation-based system, I assure you!

Answer (score 0):

A FFT does only make sense when you already have sort the image with kd-tree or a hierarchical tree. I would suggest to map the image 2d rgb values to a 1d curve and reducing some complexity before a frequency analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an exact algorithm to propose because I have found that target detection method depend greatly on the specific situation. Instead, I have some tips and advices. Here is what I would suggest: find a specific characteristic of your target and design your code around it.

For example, if you have access to the color image, use the fact that Wally doesn't have much green and blue color. Subtract the average of blue and green from the red image, you'll have a much better starting point. (Apply the same operation on both the image and the target.) This will not work, though, if the noise is color-dependent (ie: is different on each color).

You could then use correlation on the transformed images with better result. The negative point of correlation is that it will work only with an exact cut-out of the first image... Not very useful if you need to find the target to help you find the target! Instead, I suppose that an averaged version of your target (a combination of many Wally pictures) would work up to some point.

My final advice: In my personal experience of working with noisy images, spectral analysis is usually a good thing because the noise tend to contaminate only one particular scale (which would hopefully be a different scale than Wally's!) In addition, correlation is mathematically equivalent to comparing the spectral characteristic of your image and the target.